# Codeigniter upload file button to open external folder on the server

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I have upload function in codeigniter that works ok on a localhost. When I click Upload file button it opens folder on a local PC... I was wondering if it is possible to open external folder(on another server, not local) when user clicks "Upload" button? There must be some sort of "default path to open" in configuration, but I could not find it so far as I've never tried the upload function before...
Thanks

Comment: There is no such a feature in codeigniter.

Comment: No, this is just standard browser behavior for html `<input type="file">` What you are describing isnt a file upload at all, as the user wont be uploading anything (just picking something already on the server).

Comment: That's not encouraging... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ronak have said -  No freaking way!